# Scipy not importing linear programming

Tags: python, scipy, python-import, importerror, linear-programming

I am trying to use linprog from scipy, to solve a linear programming problem. But I get an import error.

Here is the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linprog'
```

Code is below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt

bounds = []
for i in xrange(6):
    bounds.append((0, 1))
bounds = tuple(bounds)
W = np.zeros((3, 6))
W[1, 2] = 0.4
W[2, 3] = 0.5
b = np.transpose(np.zeros(3))
b[1] = 0.8
b[2] = 0.25

res = opt.linprog(c, A_eq=W, b_eq=b, bounds=bounds, options={"disp": True})
```

I am using Python 2.7.10 and Scipy 0.13.0b1

Comment: yes there is, I forgot to past it; edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scipy version is heavily outdated (from 2013, i would guess).

The linprog-part of the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) say:

> New in version 0.15.0.

while yours is *Scipy 0.13.0b1*.

So the takeaway message is: your version does not support this optimizer.

(This error is gone using a recent scipy, although the code is still broken: no c defined)